# Regex number validation isolating phone number and country code

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I am pretty much entirely new to writing regex, but i have gotten a task where i must create a phone number validation system.

Currently it is a bit of a headache for me.

My current progress has led me to:

```
^([+]45|[(][+]45[)]?|[(]0045[)]|0045)?\s*([0-9]{8})$
```

There are two things i need to achieve:

1. Country code.
   The country code can be written in various formats.

   1. With a plus preceding the country code
   2. With a plus preceding the country code but in parantheses
   3. With 00 preceding the country code
   4. With 00 preceding the country code but in parantheses
2. The Phone number
   The phone number is assumed to always be from my country (which is why the country code always
   the same as well

The issue comes when 00 is used for the country code. While I want to require the phone number to be with 8 digits, when the country code is 0045, only 4 digits for the phone number are required to get a "true" result.

I just cannot figure out how to ensure that this will be the case.
Can this even be done in a reasonable way?

Comment: Provide an example and expectation

Answer (score 2):

To match 8 digits for the phone number excluding the prefix, you can match either +45 or (45) or (0045) or 0045 followed by 8 digits.

Or match 8 digits asserting the number does not start with `00` for a country code using a negative lookahead `(?!00)`

```
^(?:\+45|\(\+45\)|\(0045\)|0045|(?!00))\d{8}$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\+45|\(\+45\)|\(0045\)|0045|(?!00)` Match either of the alternations, or assert not `00` at the start of the string
- `)` Close non capture group
- `\d{8}` Match 8 digits
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/c9g0zz/1)

Comment: The issue is that 8 digits are required for the phone number, and my original examples can interpret 00451234 as an 8 digit phone number, where it actually is a country code and 4 digits.

Comment: Being a complete newbie to regex, just to see if i have understood it correctly:

- The backslashes are used as i do not require a group of characters, but  for single characters that should be required?

- The non capture group removes the section of the string from the rest of the sequence? as such the characters are not considered when evaluating the rest of the sequence?

- The negative lookahead states that the non capture group cannot start with 00, or is it the "phone number" that cannot start with 00 ?

Comment: @UlrikKrogeSloth The `(?:` notation is a non capture group. It groups the alternatives `+45` `(+45)` `(0045)` 
 and `0045` to be valid options to match. The backslash before the plus sign `\+` is to escape the character to match a literal plus sign as the plus sign in regex by itself has a special meaning of being a quantifier denoting repetition of 1 or more times. The negative lookahead `(?!00)` is a non consuming assertion (does not match anything) which will be either true or false asserting that from the current location what is directly to the right is not `00`

Comment: So the pattern matches either 1 out of the first 4 alternatives, or if the last assertion is true (then that part will not match anything) followed by matching 8 digits.

Answer (score 0):

I have altered the expression to:
^(^([+]45|[(][+]45[)]?|[(]0045[)]|0045)?\s*([1-9]{1})([0-9]{7})$

Which works for my purpose

But better solutions might be required later as international numbers might also be accepted at a later point.

Comment: Why + and () are in brackets? I think these may escaped instead of being in brackets

Comment: Because i am a newbie to regex :D